# Failed to load resource net::ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, encoding, base64

I am not able to display the avatar images. I am using multiavatar api to display 4 random avatars. The code fetches four random images from the specified API, processes them by converting them to base64 strings, and updates the component's state with the resulting data. I have rechecked the URL and and it is correct but still I am getting an error "Failed to load resource  net::ERR_INVALID_URL" in the console and the avatar images are not getting displayed.
This is what is getting displayed on my screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uyOi.png)
Console error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQKpm.png)

> The part in which I am getting error in console

```
const apiKey = '3a6j4ToRdWLPyA';
const api = `https://api.multiavatar.com/45678945`;
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                const image = await axios.get(
                    `${api}/${Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}?apikey=${apiKey}`
                );
                const buffer = Buffer.from(image.data);
                data.push(buffer.toString("base64"));
                console.log(data);
            }
            setAvatars(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [api]);
```

> The entire component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import loader from "../assets/loader.gif";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { setAvatarRoute } from '../utils/APIRoutes';

const SetAvatar = () => {
    const apiKey = '3a6j4ToRdWLPyA';
    const api = `https://api.multiavatar.com/45678945`;
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [avatars, setAvatars] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [selectedAvatar, setSelectedAvatar] = useState(undefined);
    const toastOptions = {
        position: "bottom-right",
        autoClose: 8000,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        theme: "dark",
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData2 = async () => {
            if (!localStorage.getItem(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_KEY))
                navigate("/login");
        };
        fetchData2();
    });

    const setProfilePicture = async () => {
        if (selectedAvatar === undefined) {
            toast.error("Please select an avatar", toastOptions);
        } else {
            const user = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_KEY));

            const { data } = await axios.post(`${setAvatarRoute}/${user._id}`, {
                image: avatars[selectedAvatar],
            });

            if (data.isSet) {
                user.isAvatarImageSet = true;
                user.avatarImage = data.image;
                localStorage.setItem(
                    process.env.REACT_APP_LOCALHOST_KEY,
                    JSON.stringify(user)
                );
                navigate("/");
            } else {
                toast.error("Error setting avatar. Please try again.", toastOptions);
            }
        }
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                const image = await axios.get(
                    `${api}/${Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)}?apikey=${apiKey}`
                );
                const buffer = Buffer.from(image.data);
                data.push(buffer.toString("base64"));
            }
            setAvatars(data);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [api]);

   

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading ? (
                <Container>
                    <img src={loader} alt="loader" className='loader' />
                </Container>
            ) : (
                <Container>
                    <div className="title-container">
                        <h1>Pick an Avatar as your profile picture</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="avatars">
                        {avatars.map((avatar, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div
                                    className={`avatar ${selectedAvatar === index ? "selected" : ""}`}
                                    key={index}
                                >
                                    <img
                                        src={`data:image/svg+xml;base64;${avatar}`}
                                        alt="avatar"
                                        key={avatar}
                                        onClick={() => setSelectedAvatar(index)}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
                    <button onClick={setProfilePicture} className='submit-btn'>
                        Set as Profile Picture
                    </button>
                    <ToastContainer />
                </Container>
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default SetAvatar;
```

Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: base64, not base64;

Comment: Ohhh!! my bad bro thank u so much. Wasted hours trying to figure out a solution only to know that it was a silly mistake. Thnx my issue is resolved.